# Pay pal cart options being set to only one and not a drop down with multiples.

Tags: paypal

How do I create an add to cart option on Paypal without a drop down box. I have single unique items only so don't want to offer a choice of more than one. How do i do this? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this snippet and make your customizations on the tag values:

```html
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" value="_cart" name="cmd">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="add">
<input type="hidden" value="usm@email.com" name="business">
<input type="hidden" value="USD" name="currency_code">
<input type="hidden" value="http://yourReturnURL/" name="return">
<input type="hidden" value="Carrot Soup" name="item_name">
<input type="hidden" value="12" name="amount">
<input type="image" name="submit" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks pp_pduan but I can buy more than one of these still. i want to only be able to buy one. I want it to say no more are available after i've bought one